# Slick2D collision detection with multiple collision boxes

Tags: java, slick2d

I draw a rectangle with 4 smaller rectangles on all the sides for collision detection.
But when I collide with the I get some weird result, like the player is going through them.
My Block Class

```
    public Block(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);

        top = new Rectangle(this.x+2, this.y, this.width-4, 4);
        bottom = new Rectangle(this.x+2, this.y+this.height-4, this.width-4, 4);
        left = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 4, this.height);
        right = new Rectangle(this.x+this.width-4, this.y, 4, this.height);

    }
```

and here is my collision detection

```
    for (Block b : blocks) {
        if (player.intersects(b.top)) {
            player.setY(player.getY()-1);
            velY = 0;
        } else if (player.intersects(b.left)) {
            player.setX(player.getX()-1);
            velX = 0;
        } else if (player.intersects(b.bottom)) {
            player.setY(player.getY()+1);
            velY = 0;
        } else if (player.intersects(b.right)) {
            player.setX(player.getX()+1);
            velX = 0;
        }
    }
```

I really need this to work :/ Can I get any help?

Comment: I think the problem is the player goes so fast that an intersection never occurs in distict frames. Basically, in one frame the player is outside the box, then the next frame velocity is so fast that it takes the player straight through. I advise getting rid of the smaller rectangles and testing collision with the box itself.

Comment: Also Slick2D is kind of obsolete now with new engines like libGDX ( http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com )

Comment: I've been thinking about switching to libGDX, but I'm still debating whether or not it's worth the effort :/

Comment: When the *same code* automatically compiles to desktop Java, android, iOS, and HTML5/WebGL? Definitely worth the effort (if multi platform is desirable)

Comment: Ok, thanks for this advise, I'll be working with libgdx from now on :)